# tuple not sorting in correct order (swift3)

Tags: swift, sorting, struct, tuples

My code is supposed to use a tuple to sort a string and int. String is supposed to be in order from a- z and int is supposed to be in order from 9-1. Right now no order is being kept and its not being sorted.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var number = [Int]()
    var yourArray = [String]()
    @IBOutlet var txtb: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txta: UITextField!

    @IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {
        yourArray.append((txta.text!))
           number.append(Int(txtb.text!)!)
           let tuples = zip(yourArray,number)

            let sorted = tuples.sorted(by: { this, next in
              if this.0 < next.0 {
                   return true
            } else if this.0 == next.0 {
                   return this.1 < next.1
               } else {
                    return false
                }})
            bad.mm.append(String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")))

    }}
struct bad {
    static var mm = [String]()}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `switch` instead to create your flow control - you'll be able to ensure you return the proper value in every condition. You can even comma separate multiple conditions for the same return value.

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output with your question, it will help to identify what are you trying to do

Comment: @arunjos007 I added a pic. What you can see in the pic is if I type a,2 then a,1. a,2 is still being printed ahead of a,1so it is not following the sorting logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like working?.

```
let tuples:[(String,Int)] = [("baa",2), ("abc",50),("a",10)]

let result = tuples.sorted(by: { this, next in
  if this.0 < next.0 {
    return true
  } else if this.0 == next.0 {
    return this.1 < next.1
  } else {
    return false
  }})

print(result)
```

Comment: Your right this work if the data is already defined. For whatever reason trying to define the variable inputs its not working.

Comment: @Sam Burns,  Can you print out these 2. 
yourArray.append((txta.text!))
number.append(Int(txtb.text!)!)

Comment: I can see why you want to print those 2. The only thing in that is being printed is () in both.